# Scaled gamma random variable with threshold

Tags: probability, density-function, gamma-distribution

Let's say we have gamma random variables X, which has $k$-shape parameter and $\theta$-scale parameter and threshold parameter $\alpha$ ($x>\alpha$).

What is the distribution of cX, is it still gamma? If it is, how can I find parameters of such distribution?

Comment: What do you mean by a threshold? Do you mean, sample a Gamma random variable (RV), check whether it is greater than $\alpha$, and if not then reject it and sample another? Or do you mean sample a Gamma RV and add a constant? Do you mean something else?

Comment: @newbie A truncated gamma is not gamma so the word *still* in there is puzzling; it already wasn't gamma before you scaled it

Comment: Yes, I mean truncated gamma distribution, which is a Person type 3 RV. Let's not call if gamma then. However, we know pdf for such RV. What about a transformation of such RV (for instance, cX?)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to your terminology, so let me break one of my own rules and use my terminology. Suppose we have a gamma random variable with parameters $\alpha,\beta,$ such that the density function is given by
$$f(y)=\frac{y^{\alpha-1}\,e^{-y/\beta}}{\Gamma(\alpha)\,\beta^\alpha}.$$
It can be shown that the moment-generating function for this Gamma RV is $(1-\beta t)^{-\alpha}.$ Now it is a fact that if you take the moment-generating function for $Y$ and compare it with that of $aY,$ you simply need to replace $t$ with $at.$ So let us multiply $Y$ by $c$ to get $cY,$ and the moment-generating function will be $(1-\beta c t)^{-\alpha}.$ So if $c>0,$ the new parameters of the distribution will be $\alpha$ unchanged, but the second parameter will be $c\beta.$